# Hit kernel panic like this. Have no idea what may be the cause

Tags: kernel

I was trying to boot up my own packed ubuntu image (16.04 base) but hit a kernel panic as below. I cannot further troubleshoot the problem based on call traces and error code. Thanks!

```
[    0.000000] Initializing cgroup subsys cpuset
[    0.000000] Initializing cgroup subsys cpu
[    0.000000] Initializing cgroup subsys cpuacct
[    0.000000] Linux version 4.4.0-96-generic (buildd@lgw01-10) (gcc version 5.4.0 20160609 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) ) #119-Ubuntu SMP Tue Sep 12 14:59:54 UTC 2017 (Ubuntu 4.4.0-96.119-generic 4.4.83)
[    0.000000] Command line: ro root=/dev/sda5 net.ifnames=0 console=ttyS0 console=tty0  
[    0.000000] KERNEL supported cpus:
[    0.000000]   Intel GenuineIntel
[    0.000000]   AMD AuthenticAMD
[    0.000000]   Centaur CentaurHauls
[    0.000000] x86/fpu: xstate_offset[2]:  576, xstate_sizes[2]:  256
[    0.000000] x86/fpu: Supporting XSAVE feature 0x01: 'x87 floating point registers'
[    0.000000] x86/fpu: Supporting XSAVE feature 0x02: 'SSE registers'
[    0.000000] x86/fpu: Supporting XSAVE feature 0x04: 'AVX registers'
[    0.000000] x86/fpu: Enabled xstate features 0x7, context size is 832 bytes, using 'standard' format.
[    0.000000] x86/fpu: Using 'eager' FPU context switches.
[    0.000000] e820: BIOS-provided physical RAM map:
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000000000000-0x000000000009fbff] usable
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000000009fc00-0x000000000009ffff] reserved
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000000f0000-0x00000000000fffff] reserved
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000000100000-0x000000007ffdffff] usable
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000007ffe0000-0x000000007fffffff] reserved
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000feffc000-0x00000000feffffff] reserved
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000fffc0000-0x00000000ffffffff] reserved
[    0.000000] NX (Execute Disable) protection: active
[    0.000000] SMBIOS 2.8 present.
[    0.000000] Hypervisor detected: KVM
[    0.000000] e820: last_pfn = 0x7ffe0 max_arch_pfn = 0x400000000
[    0.000000] x86/PAT: Configuration [0-7]: WB  WC  UC- UC  WB  WC  UC- WT  
[    0.000000] found SMP MP-table at [mem 0x000f6600-0x000f660f] mapped at [ffff8800000f6600]
[    0.000000] Scanning 1 areas for low memory corruption
[    0.000000] RAMDISK: [mem 0x36051000-0x37feffff]
[    0.000000] ACPI: Early table checksum verification disabled
[    0.000000] ACPI: RSDP 0x00000000000F63D0 000014 (v00 BOCHS )
[    0.000000] ACPI: RSDT 0x000000007FFE16CA 000030 (v01 BOCHS  BXPCRSDT 00000001 BXPC 00000001)
[    0.000000] ACPI: FACP 0x000000007FFE0C14 000074 (v01 BOCHS  BXPCFACP 00000001 BXPC 00000001)
[    0.000000] ACPI: DSDT 0x000000007FFE0040 000BD4 (v01 BOCHS  BXPCDSDT 00000001 BXPC 00000001)
[    0.000000] ACPI: FACS 0x000000007FFE0000 000040
[    0.000000] ACPI: SSDT 0x000000007FFE0C88 0009C2 (v01 BOCHS  BXPCSSDT 00000001 BXPC 00000001)
[    0.000000] ACPI: APIC 0x000000007FFE164A 000080 (v01 BOCHS  BXPCAPIC 00000001 BXPC 00000001)
[    0.000000] No NUMA configuration found
[    0.000000] Faking a node at [mem 0x0000000000000000-0x000000007ffdffff]
[    0.000000] NODE_DATA(0) allocated [mem 0x7ffdb000-0x7ffdffff]
[    0.000000] kvm-clock: Using msrs 4b564d01 and 4b564d00
[    0.000000] kvm-clock: cpu 0, msr 0:7ffd3001, primary cpu clock
[    0.000000] kvm-clock: using sched offset of 16588663618 cycles
[    0.000000] clocksource: kvm-clock: mask: 0xffffffffffffffff max_cycles: 0x1cd42e4dffb, max_idle_ns: 881590591483 ns
[    0.000000] Zone ranges:
[    0.000000]   DMA      [mem 0x0000000000001000-0x0000000000ffffff]
[    0.000000]   DMA32    [mem 0x0000000001000000-0x000000007ffdffff]
[    0.000000]   Normal   empty
[    0.000000]   Device   empty
[    0.000000] Movable zone start for each node
[    0.000000] Early memory node ranges
[    0.000000]   node   0: [mem 0x0000000000001000-0x000000000009efff]
[    0.000000]   node   0: [mem 0x0000000000100000-0x000000007ffdffff]
[    0.000000] Initmem setup node 0 [mem 0x0000000000001000-0x000000007ffdffff]
[    0.000000] ACPI: PM-Timer IO Port: 0x608
[    0.000000] ACPI: LAPIC_NMI (acpi_id[0xff] dfl dfl lint[0x1])
[    0.000000] IOAPIC[0]: apic_id 0, version 17, address 0xfec00000, GSI 0-23
[    0.000000] ACPI: INT_SRC_OVR (bus 0 bus_irq 0 global_irq 2 dfl dfl)
[    0.000000] ACPI: INT_SRC_OVR (bus 0 bus_irq 5 global_irq 5 high level)
[    0.000000] ACPI: INT_SRC_OVR (bus 0 bus_irq 9 global_irq 9 high level)
[    0.000000] ACPI: INT_SRC_OVR (bus 0 bus_irq 10 global_irq 10 high level)
[    0.000000] ACPI: INT_SRC_OVR (bus 0 bus_irq 11 global_irq 11 high level)
[    0.000000] Using ACPI (MADT) for SMP configuration information
[    0.000000] smpboot: Allowing 2 CPUs, 0 hotplug CPUs
[    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0x00000000-0x00000fff]
[    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0x0009f000-0x0009ffff]
[    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0x000a0000-0x000effff]
[    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0x000f0000-0x000fffff]
[    0.000000] e820: [mem 0x80000000-0xfeffbfff] available for PCI devices
[    0.000000] Booting paravirtualized kernel on KVM
[    0.000000] clocksource: refined-jiffies: mask: 0xffffffff max_cycles: 0xffffffff, max_idle_ns: 7645519600211568 ns
[    0.000000] setup_percpu: NR_CPUS:512 nr_cpumask_bits:512 nr_cpu_ids:2 nr_node_ids:1
[    0.000000] PERCPU: Embedded 34 pages/cpu @ffff88007fc00000 s98328 r8192 d32744 u1048576
[    0.000000] KVM setup async PF for cpu 0
[    0.000000] kvm-stealtime: cpu 0, msr 7fc0d9c0
[    0.000000] Built 1 zonelists in Node order, mobility grouping on.  Total pages: 515945
[    0.000000] Policy zone: DMA32
[    0.000000] Kernel command line: ro root=/dev/sda5 net.ifnames=0 HexSaveDefault=1  console=ttyS0 console=tty0  
[    0.000000] PID hash table entries: 4096 (order: 3, 32768 bytes)
[    0.000000] Memory: 2012316K/2096632K available (8479K kernel code, 1294K rwdata, 3984K rodata, 1492K init, 1316K bss, 84316K reserved, 0K cma-reserved)
[    0.000000] SLUB: HWalign=64, Order=0-3, MinObjects=0, CPUs=2, Nodes=1
[    0.000000] Hierarchical RCU implementation.
[    0.000000]  Build-time adjustment of leaf fanout to 64.
[    0.000000]  RCU restricting CPUs from NR_CPUS=512 to nr_cpu_ids=2.
[    0.000000] RCU: Adjusting geometry for rcu_fanout_leaf=64, nr_cpu_ids=2
[    0.000000] NR_IRQS:33024 nr_irqs:440 16
[    0.000000] Console: colour *CGA 80x25
[    0.000000] console [tty0] enabled
[    0.000000] console [ttyS0] enabled
[    0.000000] tsc: Detected 2693.760 MHz processor
[    0.330119] Calibrating delay loop (skipped) preset value.. 5387.52 BogoMIPS (lpj=10775040)
[    0.332686] pid_max: default: 32768 minimum: 301
[    0.334118] ACPI: Core revision 20150930
[    0.336608] ACPI: 2 ACPI AML tables successfully acquired and loaded
[    0.338830] Security Framework initialized
[    0.340161] Yama: becoming mindful.
[    0.341123] AppArmor: AppArmor initialized
[    0.344105] Dentry cache hash table entries: 262144 (order: 9, 2097152 bytes)
[    0.352060] Inode-cache hash table entries: 131072 (order: 8, 1048576 bytes)
[    0.357141] Mount-cache hash table entries: 4096 (order: 3, 32768 bytes)
[    0.360059] Mountpoint-cache hash table entries: 4096 (order: 3, 32768 bytes)
[    0.364492] Initializing cgroup subsys io
[    0.366098] Initializing cgroup subsys memory
[    0.369047] Initializing cgroup subsys devices
[    0.370824] Initializing cgroup subsys freezer
[    0.372524] Initializing cgroup subsys net_cls
[    0.375570] Initializing cgroup subsys perf_event
[    0.377496] Initializing cgroup subsys net_prio
[    0.379184] Initializing cgroup subsys hugetlb
[    0.381188] Initializing cgroup subsys pids
[    0.384563] mce: CPU supports 10 MCE banks
[    0.386899] Last level iTLB entries: 4KB 0, 2MB 0, 4MB 0
[    0.389834] Last level dTLB entries: 4KB 0, 2MB 0, 4MB 0, 1GB 0
[    0.401775] Freeing SMP alternatives memory: 32K
[    0.441764] ftrace: allocating 32146 entries in 126 pages
[    0.603936] smpboot: APIC(0) Converting physical 0 to logical package 0
[    0.614861] smpboot: APIC(1) Converting physical 1 to logical package 1
[    0.621250] smpboot: Max logical packages: 2
[    0.625045] x2apic enabled
[    0.634576] Switched APIC routing to physical x2apic.
[    0.644776] ..TIMER: vector=0x30 apic1=0 pin1=2 apic2=-1 pin2=-1
[    0.652237] smpboot: CPU0: Intel Core Processor (Haswell, no TSX) (family: 0x6, model: 0x3c, stepping: 0x1)
[    0.662700] Performance Events: unsupported p6 CPU model 60 no PMU driver, software events only.
[    0.668197] x86: Booting SMP configuration:
[    0.670995] .... node  #0, CPUs:      #1
[    0.674916] kvm-clock: cpu 1, msr 0:7ffd3041, secondary cpu clock
[    0.704805] x86: Booted up 1 node, 2 CPUs
[    0.704834] KVM setup async PF for cpu 1
[    0.704854] kvm-stealtime: cpu 1, msr 7fd0d9c0
[    0.709253] smpboot: Total of 2 processors activated (10775.04 BogoMIPS)
[    0.713747] devtmpfs: initialized
[    0.717289] evm: security.selinux
[    0.718409] evm: security.SMACK64
[    0.720113] evm: security.SMACK64EXEC
[    0.722698] evm: security.SMACK64TRANSMUTE
[    0.724276] evm: security.SMACK64MMAP
[    0.726836] evm: security.ima
[    0.728487] evm: security.capability
[    0.731147] clocksource: jiffies: mask: 0xffffffff max_cycles: 0xffffffff, max_idle_ns: 7645041785100000 ns
[    0.735774] futex hash table entries: 512 (order: 3, 32768 bytes)
[    0.738834] pinctrl core: initialized pinctrl subsystem
[    0.742055] RTC time: 14:50:29, date: 11/28/17
[    0.743833] NET: Registered protocol family 16
[    0.761609] cpuidle: using governor ladder
[    0.779736] cpuidle: using governor menu
[    0.781350] PCCT header not found.
[    0.782634] ACPI: bus type PCI registered
[    0.784622] acpiphp: ACPI Hot Plug PCI Controller Driver version: 0.5
[    0.788997] PCI: Using configuration type 1 for base access
[    0.809528] ACPI: Added _OSI(Module Device)
[    0.812806] ACPI: Added _OSI(Processor Device)
[    0.814089] ACPI: Added _OSI(3.0 _SCP Extensions)
[    0.816881] ACPI: Added _OSI(Processor Aggregator Device)
[    0.820619] ACPI: Interpreter enabled
[    0.822372] ACPI: (supports S0 S5)
[    0.823714] ACPI: Using IOAPIC for interrupt routing
[    0.826630] PCI: Using host bridge windows from ACPI; if necessary, use "pci=nocrs" and report a bug
[    0.841202] ACPI: PCI Root Bridge [PCI0] (domain 0000 [bus 00-ff])
[    0.842754] acpi PNP0A03:00: _OSC: OS supports [ASPM ClockPM Segments MSI]
[    0.846273] acpi PNP0A03:00: _OSC failed (AE_NOT_FOUND); disabling ASPM
[    0.849617] acpi PNP0A03:00: fail to add MMCONFIG information, can't access extended PCI configuration space under this bridge.
[    0.855366] acpiphp: Slot [2] registered
[    0.857626] acpiphp: Slot [3] registered
[    0.861704] acpiphp: Slot [5] registered
[    0.865486] acpiphp: Slot [6] registered
[    0.868116] acpiphp: Slot [7] registered
[    0.870814] acpiphp: Slot [8] registered
[    0.874448] acpiphp: Slot [9] registered
[    0.876912] acpiphp: Slot [10] registered
[    0.879369] acpiphp: Slot [11] registered
[    0.883668] acpiphp: Slot [12] registered
[    0.890047] acpiphp: Slot [13] registered
[    0.895578] acpiphp: Slot [14] registered
[    0.904171] acpiphp: Slot [15] registered
[    0.909447] acpiphp: Slot [16] registered
[    0.914477] acpiphp: Slot [17] registered
[    0.916617] acpiphp: Slot [18] registered
[    0.921154] acpiphp: Slot [19] registered
[    0.924318] acpiphp: Slot [20] registered
[    0.929603] acpiphp: Slot [21] registered
[    0.933084] acpiphp: Slot [22] registered
[    0.935703] acpiphp: Slot [23] registered
[    0.940325] acpiphp: Slot [24] registered
[    0.941899] acpiphp: Slot [25] registered
[    0.946412] acpiphp: Slot [26] registered
[    0.949923] acpiphp: Slot [27] registered
[    0.953719] acpiphp: Slot [28] registered
[    0.957156] acpiphp: Slot [29] registered
[    0.961717] acpiphp: Slot [30] registered
[    0.965760] acpiphp: Slot [31] registered
[    0.968830] PCI host bridge to bus 0000:00
[    0.971624] pci_bus 0000:00: root bus resource [io  0x0000-0x0cf7 window]
[    0.975302] pci_bus 0000:00: root bus resource [io  0x0d00-0xffff window]
[    0.982130] pci_bus 0000:00: root bus resource [mem 0x000a0000-0x000bffff window]
[    0.987748] pci_bus 0000:00: root bus resource [mem 0x80000000-0xfebfffff window]
[    0.995485] pci_bus 0000:00: root bus resource [bus 00-ff]
[    1.018475] pci 0000:00:01.1: legacy IDE quirk: reg 0x10: [io  0x01f0-0x01f7]
[    1.038052] pci 0000:00:01.1: legacy IDE quirk: reg 0x14: [io  0x03f6]
[    1.046454] pci 0000:00:01.1: legacy IDE quirk: reg 0x18: [io  0x0170-0x0177]
[    1.058854] pci 0000:00:01.1: legacy IDE quirk: reg 0x1c: [io  0x0376]
[    1.069983] pci 0000:00:01.3: quirk: [io  0x0600-0x063f] claimed by PIIX4 ACPI
[    1.079469] pci 0000:00:01.3: quirk: [io  0x0700-0x070f] claimed by PIIX4 SMB
[    1.148233] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKA] (IRQs 5 *10 11)
[    1.151513] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKB] (IRQs 5 *10 11)
[    1.155518] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKC] (IRQs 5 10 *11)
[    1.161980] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKD] (IRQs 5 10 *11)
[    1.167386] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKS] (IRQs *9)
[    1.171537] ACPI: Enabled 16 GPEs in block 00 to 0F
[    1.177303] vgaarb: loaded
[    1.180498] SCSI subsystem initialized
[    1.184656] ACPI: bus type USB registered
[    1.187780] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbfs
[    1.192934] usbcore: registered new interface driver hub
[    1.198642] usbcore: registered new device driver usb
[    1.202943] PCI: Using ACPI for IRQ routing
[    1.214998] NetLabel: Initializing
[    1.216734] NetLabel:  domain hash size = 128
[    1.217606] NetLabel:  protocols = UNLABELED CIPSOv4
[    1.219368] NetLabel:  unlabeled traffic allowed by default
[    1.224192] amd_nb: Cannot enumerate AMD northbridges
[    1.233381] clocksource: Switched to clocksource kvm-clock
[    1.253677] AppArmor: AppArmor Filesystem Enabled
[    1.255373] pnp: PnP ACPI init
[    1.257055] pnp: PnP ACPI: found 5 devices
[    1.283055] clocksource: acpi_pm: mask: 0xffffff max_cycles: 0xffffff, max_idle_ns: 2085701024 ns
[    1.296539] NET: Registered protocol family 2
[    1.303065] TCP established hash table entries: 16384 (order: 5, 131072 bytes)
[    1.316690] TCP bind hash table entries: 16384 (order: 6, 262144 bytes)
[    1.324319] TCP: Hash tables configured (established 16384 bind 16384)
[    1.334910] UDP hash table entries: 1024 (order: 3, 32768 bytes)
[    1.342313] UDP-Lite hash table entries: 1024 (order: 3, 32768 bytes)
[    1.358427] NET: Registered protocol family 1
[    1.364649] pci 0000:00:00.0: Limiting direct PCI/PCI transfers
[    1.372273] pci 0000:00:01.0: PIIX3: Enabling Passive Release
[    1.379877] pci 0000:00:01.0: Activating ISA DMA hang workarounds
[    1.416218] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKD] enabled at IRQ 11
[    1.498846] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKA] enabled at IRQ 10
[    1.546975] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKB] enabled at IRQ 10
[    1.590073] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKC] enabled at IRQ 11
[    1.617236] Unpacking initramfs...
[    2.067848] Freeing initrd memory: 32380K
[    2.069413] Scanning for low memory corruption every 60 seconds
[    2.079112] audit: initializing netlink subsys (disabled)
[    2.082725] audit: type=2000 audit(1511880630.105:1): initialized
[    2.086509] Initialise system trusted keyring
[    2.090164] HugeTLB registered 2 MB page size, pre-allocated 0 pages
[    2.094019] zbud: loaded
[    2.096506] VFS: Disk quotas dquot_6.6.0
[    2.099368] VFS: Dquot-cache hash table entries: 512 (order 0, 4096 bytes)
[    2.103791] squashfs: version 4.0 (2009/01/31) Phillip Lougher
[    2.106657] fuse init (API version 7.23)
[    2.108805] Key type big_key registered
[    2.110987] Allocating IMA MOK and blacklist keyrings.
[    2.117724] Key type asymmetric registered
[    2.120499] Asymmetric key parser 'x509' registered
[    2.122924] Block layer SCSI generic (bsg) driver version 0.4 loaded (major 249)
[    2.127344] io scheduler noop registered
[    2.129175] io scheduler deadline registered (default)
[    2.132334] io scheduler cfq registered
[    2.134161] pci_hotplug: PCI Hot Plug PCI Core version: 0.5
[    2.136777] pciehp: PCI Express Hot Plug Controller Driver version: 0.4
[    2.140645] input: Power Button as /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXPWRBN:00/input/input0
[    2.143059] ACPI: Power Button [PWRF]
[    2.146430] GHES: HEST is not enabled!
[    2.168987] virtio-pci 0000:00:02.0: virtio_pci: leaving for legacy driver
[    2.193063] virtio-pci 0000:00:03.0: virtio_pci: leaving for legacy driver
[    2.198742] Serial: 8250/16550 driver, 32 ports, IRQ sharing enabled
[    2.229064] 00:04: ttyS0 at I/O 0x3f8 (irq = 4, base_baud = 115200) is a 16550A
[    2.232352] Linux agpgart interface v0.103
[    2.235919] loop: module loaded
[    2.238505] scsi host0: ata_piix
[    2.240206] scsi host1: ata_piix
[    2.241099] ata1: PATA max MWDMA2 cmd 0x1f0 ctl 0x3f6 bmdma 0xc0a0 irq 14
[    2.244168] ata2: PATA max MWDMA2 cmd 0x170 ctl 0x376 bmdma 0xc0a8 irq 15
[    2.246815] libphy: Fixed MDIO Bus: probed
[    2.248215] tun: Universal TUN/TAP device driver, 1.6
[    2.251711] tun: (C) 1999-2004 Max Krasnyansky <maxk@qualcomm.com>
[    2.258143] PPP generic driver version 2.4.2
[    2.259329] ehci_hcd: USB 2.0 'Enhanced' Host Controller (EHCI) Driver
[    2.264433] ehci-pci: EHCI PCI platform driver
[    2.290571] ehci-pci 0000:00:04.7: EHCI Host Controller
[    2.292607] ehci-pci 0000:00:04.7: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 1
[    2.296969] ehci-pci 0000:00:04.7: irq 11, io mem 0xfebc1000
[    2.310786] ehci-pci 0000:00:04.7: USB 2.0 started, EHCI 1.00
[    2.315127] usb usb1: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0002
[    2.318454] usb usb1: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    2.319631] usb usb1: Product: EHCI Host Controller
[    2.320445] usb usb1: Manufacturer: Linux 4.4.0-96-generic ehci_hcd
[    2.321747] usb usb1: SerialNumber: 0000:00:04.7
[    2.322836] hub 1-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    2.323806] hub 1-0:1.0: 6 ports detected
[    2.325097] ehci-platform: EHCI generic platform driver
[    2.327161] ohci_hcd: USB 1.1 'Open' Host Controller (OHCI) Driver
[    2.329080] ohci-pci: OHCI PCI platform driver
[    2.330683] ohci-platform: OHCI generic platform driver
[    2.333455] uhci_hcd: USB Universal Host Controller Interface driver
[    2.357517] uhci_hcd 0000:00:04.0: UHCI Host Controller
[    2.359445] uhci_hcd 0000:00:04.0: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 2
[    2.363101] uhci_hcd 0000:00:04.0: detected 2 ports
[    2.364950] uhci_hcd 0000:00:04.0: irq 11, io base 0x0000c040
[    2.367754] usb usb2: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0001
[    2.371134] usb usb2: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    2.374405] usb usb2: Product: UHCI Host Controller
[    2.377013] usb usb2: Manufacturer: Linux 4.4.0-96-generic uhci_hcd
[    2.380796] usb usb2: SerialNumber: 0000:00:04.0
[    2.384254] hub 2-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    2.386918] hub 2-0:1.0: 2 ports detected
[    2.398790] ata1.00: ATA-7: QEMU HARDDISK, 2.5+, max UDMA/100
[    2.401633] ata1.00: 41943040 sectors, multi 16: LBA48 
[    2.403126] ata1.01: ATAPI: QEMU DVD-ROM, 2.5+, max UDMA/100
[    2.405338] ata1.00: configured for MWDMA2
[    2.409955] ata1.01: configured for MWDMA2
[    2.414450] scsi 0:0:0:0: Direct-Access     ATA      QEMU HARDDISK    2.5+ PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
[    2.419596] sd 0:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 0
[    2.423868] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] 41943040 512-byte logical blocks: (21.5 GB/20.0 GiB)
[    2.444063] scsi 0:0:1:0: CD-ROM            QEMU     QEMU DVD-ROM     2.5+ PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
[    2.444077] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Write Protect is off
[    2.444089] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[    2.451240]  sda: sda1 sda2 sda3 < sda5 sda6 >
[    2.452150] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI disk
[    2.472952] uhci_hcd 0000:00:04.1: UHCI Host Controller
[    2.472966] uhci_hcd 0000:00:04.1: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 3
[    2.475718] uhci_hcd 0000:00:04.1: detected 2 ports
[    2.479009] uhci_hcd 0000:00:04.1: irq 10, io base 0x0000c060
[    2.479207] usb usb3: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0001
[    2.479208] usb usb3: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    2.479210] usb usb3: Product: UHCI Host Controller
[    2.479211] usb usb3: Manufacturer: Linux 4.4.0-96-generic uhci_hcd
[    2.479212] usb usb3: SerialNumber: 0000:00:04.1
[    2.479631] hub 3-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    2.479647] hub 3-0:1.0: 2 ports detected
[    2.567663] uhci_hcd 0000:00:04.2: UHCI Host Controller
[    2.567678] uhci_hcd 0000:00:04.2: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 4
[    2.567729] uhci_hcd 0000:00:04.2: detected 2 ports
[    2.568171] uhci_hcd 0000:00:04.2: irq 10, io base 0x0000c080
[    2.568401] usb usb4: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0001
[    2.568402] usb usb4: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    2.568403] usb usb4: Product: UHCI Host Controller
[    2.568404] usb usb4: Manufacturer: Linux 4.4.0-96-generic uhci_hcd
[    2.568405] usb usb4: SerialNumber: 0000:00:04.2
[    2.568965] hub 4-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    2.568980] hub 4-0:1.0: 2 ports detected
[    2.570476] i8042: PNP: PS/2 Controller [PNP0303:KBD,PNP0f13:MOU] at 0x60,0x64 irq 1,12
[    2.575792] serio: i8042 KBD port at 0x60,0x64 irq 1
[    2.575805] serio: i8042 AUX port at 0x60,0x64 irq 12
[    2.576267] mousedev: PS/2 mouse device common for all mice
[    2.577634] input: AT Translated Set 2 keyboard as /devices/platform/i8042/serio0/input/input1
[    2.580048] rtc_cmos 00:00: RTC can wake from S4
[    2.583335] rtc_cmos 00:00: rtc core: registered rtc_cmos as rtc0
[    2.583838] rtc_cmos 00:00: alarms up to one day, 114 bytes nvram
[    2.583856] i2c /dev entries driver
[    2.584103] device-mapper: uevent: version 1.0.3
[    2.584226] device-mapper: ioctl: 4.34.0-ioctl (2015-10-28) initialised: dm-devel@redhat.com
[    2.584243] ledtrig-cpu: registered to indicate activity on CPUs
[    2.585018] NET: Registered protocol family 10
[    2.585368] NET: Registered protocol family 17
[    2.585378] Key type dns_resolver registered
[    2.591479] microcode: CPU0 sig=0x306c1, pf=0x1, revision=0x1
[    2.593620] microcode: CPU1 sig=0x306c1, pf=0x1, revision=0x1
[    2.593704] microcode: Microcode Update Driver: v2.01 <tigran@aivazian.fsnet.co.uk>, Peter Oruba
[    2.594155] registered taskstats version 1
[    2.594174] Loading compiled-in X.509 certificates
[    2.597177] Loaded X.509 cert 'Build time autogenerated kernel key: b1a6ea8776bed2812c00d8a799f968274ef48628'
[    2.597481] zswap: loaded using pool lzo/zbud
[    2.609532] Key type trusted registered
[    2.620665] Key type encrypted registered
[    2.620673] AppArmor: AppArmor sha1 policy hashing enabled
[    2.620676] ima: No TPM chip found, activating TPM-bypass!
[    2.620694] evm: HMAC attrs: 0x1
[    2.621995]   Magic number: 9:408:840
[    2.623033] rtc_cmos 00:00: setting system clock to 2017-11-28 14:50:31 UTC (1511880631)
[    2.623144] BIOS EDD facility v0.16 2004-Jun-25, 0 devices found
[    2.623145] EDD information not available.
[    2.843356] sr 0:0:1:0: [sr0] scsi3-mmc drive: 4x/4x cd/rw xa/form2 tray
[    2.844982] cdrom: Uniform CD-ROM driver Revision: 3.20
[    2.850429] sr 0:0:1:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 5
[    2.854977] Freeing unused kernel memory: 1492K
[    2.856905] Write protecting the kernel read-only data: 14336k
[    2.859433] Freeing unused kernel memory: 1748K
[    2.861621] Freeing unused kernel memory: 112K
[    2.907160] EXT4-fs (sda5): couldn't mount as ext3 due to feature incompatibilities
[    2.917867] EXT4-fs (sda5): couldn't mount as ext2 due to feature incompatibilities
[    2.954539] Kernel panic - not syncing: Attempted to kill init! exitcode=0x00000200
[    2.954539] 
[    2.966697] CPU: 1 PID: 1 Comm: init Not tainted 4.4.0-96-generic #119-Ubuntu
[    2.974300] Hardware name: QEMU Standard PC (i440FX + PIIX, 1996), BIOS Ubuntu-1.8.2-1ubuntu1 04/01/2014
[    2.977812]  0000000000000086 f6d3a08a3f143da3 ffff88007c88fe08 ffffffff813fabd3
[    2.985893]  ffffffff81cbaea0 ffff88007c88fea0 ffff88007c88fe90 ffffffff8118d967
[    2.997601]  ffff880000000010 ffff88007c88fea0 ffff88007c88fe38 f6d3a08a3f143da3
[    3.007969] Call Trace:
[    3.011547]  [<ffffffff813fabd3>] dump_stack+0x63/0x90
[    3.016734]  [<ffffffff8118d967>] panic+0xd3/0x215
[    3.021768]  [<ffffffff811867ae>] ? perf_event_exit_task+0xbe/0x350
[    3.029981]  [<ffffffff810847b1>] do_exit+0xaf1/0xb00
[    3.036536]  [<ffffffff81084843>] do_group_exit+0x43/0xb0
[    3.042512]  [<ffffffff810848c4>] SyS_exit_group+0x14/0x20
[    3.048591]  [<ffffffff81843272>] entry_SYSCALL_64_fastpath+0x16/0x71
[    3.055099] Kernel Offset: disabled
[    3.059591] ---[ end Kernel panic - not syncing: Attempted to kill init! exitcode=0x00000200
[    3.059591]
```

Comment: Does a non-modified 16.04 image boot on this configuration? Is this a problem with the virtualization or a problem with what you've modded into the new image?

Answer (score 0):

You need to have Internet access in order to download and install all the packages needed to run the operating system. If you tried to install without an Internet connection, you are missing most of the system.

Answer (score 0):

It says It stopped the init process which stands for Initalize so try getting a live ubuntu session and fix the problem.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1338483)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).